# LaTex and R-Studio: Change color of R-Code

Tags: beamer, r, rstudio

Good afternoon

I have a question concerning the use of LaTeX and R-Studio.

Since hours I'm trying to produce R-Code (Input) in blue color and create the belonging R-Code (Output) in the black color. Does anyone know which features have to be used in order to produce straightforward such R-Code (see picture below) in Beamer?

[image]

Thank you for you advice.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Do you mean displaying some R-code in your `TeX`-document using two different colors for input and output? Are you using `listings` package therefor?

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the packages `AER`, `MASS`, and `lmtest`.  Then you can use their functions and datasets.  Here is code to install those packages and calculate the desired result:

```
install.packages("AER")
install.packages("MASS")
install.packages("lmtest")

data(RecreationDemand, package = "AER")
rd_nb <- MASS::glm.nb(trips ~ ., data = RecreationDemand)
lmtest::coeftest(rd_nb)
```

Results:

```
z test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.1219363  0.2143029  -5.2353 1.647e-07 ***
quality      0.7219990  0.0401165  17.9976 < 2.2e-16 ***
skiyes       0.6121388  0.1503029   4.0727 4.647e-05 ***
income      -0.0260588  0.0424527  -0.6138   0.53933    
userfeeyes   0.6691676  0.3530211   1.8955   0.05802 .  
costC        0.0480087  0.0091848   5.2270 1.723e-07 ***
costS       -0.0926910  0.0066534 -13.9314 < 2.2e-16 ***
costH        0.0388357  0.0077505   5.0107 5.423e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: This is pretty nonresponsive

Comment: I don't find the question to be clear.  If the question is: "how do I recreate some output I found in some beamer slides?" then I believe my answer is quite responsive. However, if the question is something about changing font color in latex or adding code chunks to an .rnw file, then I agree.